# "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" error on Hadoop Pipes 1.1.2 (pseudo-cluster)

Tags: c++, hadoop, connection, pipe, reset

I'm working with a Hadoop Pipes MapReduce application on pseudo-cluster mode that is throwing the following error:

```
2013-06-24 11:04:41,026 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol$UplinkReaderThread.run(BinaryProtocol.java:121)
```

This yields a broken pipe error that aborts the application after several attempts (all of them show the same behavior).

The interesting part is that, before running this job, I run another one that works perfectly. I've read something about intensive CPU mappers (which is basically what I've got) having issues since the connection is closed after a timeout, but I haven't found a solution for this.

I'd appreciate any guidelines for a better diagnose and hints to fix this issue. Is there any configuration parameter or piece of code I could modify to get rid of timeouts?

Thanks in advance,

Río

++++ EDIT ++++

Doing some more research I found that this version supports setting the timeout to zero.
The socket timeout can be modified in *hadoop-home*/conf/hdfs-site.xml appending something like this inside the *configuration* tag:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.socket.timeout</name>
    <value>0</value>
</property>
```

Using both zero and a high value worked for me.

++++ EDIT 2 ++++

*dfs.socket.timeout* works only for read sockets, so *dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout* should be modified as well.

I hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: How high of a value did you set? like 5000?

Comment: I used 10000, but after some months working with this and dealing with bigger problems I realized 0 works better. If there is a real problem you would probably notice anyway, even with no timeout. Good luck!